# is there any way that md5 hash function can generate numeric value in HIVE? SQL?Spark?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive

```
 my sql query 
select md5(id) as id from table_name;
its generate alphanumeric value
```

Im trying hashing my column but its alphanumeric and while aggregating it takes too much time in hive and spark.
    so can i write UDF for this or is there any another way to convert md5 in numeric value.

Comment: Why MD5? Do you really need a cryptographic hash, or would a faster/shorter hash (with some probability of collision) be sufficient? Because 32-bit hash functions return an `int`...

Comment: actually I'm looking for join two tables of billions of records so which is the best way generate key rather than md5 hash. I want unique key values for that, so is there any another hash function for generating unique values in integer? i just want unique values

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why you want to have the hash in numeric format. Usually in its ray form it's handled as `byte[]` since it's 128 bits. Converting it to a number you'd have to convert to an arbitrary precision `BigDecimal` which is not faster than `String`. If it's slow, I don't think it's because MD5 produces a string.

If you still want to try, you can convert an hex string to `BigDecimal` with

```
conv(md5(id), 16, 10)
```

Hive also has the `hash()` method that returns an int, likely using java's `hashCode()` instead of md5, you could use that instead, but I don't know your use case, so it may work for you or not. Java hash codes are only 32 bits, so much more efficient, but also higher chance of collisions.

For future reference, when asking a question on SO, beside what you're trying to do, it's useful to say a little more about what you're trying to do, so we can help you better.

Comment: conv(md5(id), 16, 10)
could you explain me in detail this query?

actually I'm looking for join two tables of billions of records so which is the best way generate key rather than md5 hash. I want unique key values for that, so is there any another hash function for generating unique values in integer? i just want unique values – Shree Batale 21 mins ago   
Thanks its working but its key length is 20 characters how can i make its length to 32 characters. Thank you so much again

Comment: `conv` in that form converts from hex (base 16) to decimal (base 10).  I am confused, don't you already have an `id` field ? Don't the two tables already have an id ? Why do you have to generate your own ? Do you realize that an hash does not guarantee uniqueness ? If working with billions of records, the chance of a collision may become non trivial.

Comment: It's impossible to give you an answer without a detailed description of the two tables you want to join, since building a unique ID depends on how the two tables are related. You'd need to build an id based on a subset of fields (one or more) that work as logical key.